# swift, alamofire cancel previous request

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

I have an NetworkRequest class, where all my alamofire requests made:

```
    class NetworkRequest {
        static let request = NetworkRequest()

        var currentRequest: Alamofire.Request?

        let dataManager = DataManager()
        let networkManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

        func downloadData<T: Film>(slug: String, provider: String, section: String, dynamic: String, anyClass: T, completion: ([T]?) -> Void ) {
            var token: String = ""

            if LOGGED_IN == true {
                token = "\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(TOKEN)!)"
            }

            let headers = [
                "Access": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
            ]

            let dataUrl = "\(BASE_URL)\(slug)\(provider)\(section)\(dynamic)"
            print(headers)
            print(dataUrl)

            if networkManager!.isReachable {

                currentRequest?.cancel()

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

                    if let url = NSURL(string: dataUrl) {
                        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, url, headers: headers)

                        request.validate().responseJSON { response in
                            switch response.result {
                            case .Success:
                                if let data = response.result.value as! [String: AnyObject]! {
                                    let receivedData = self.dataManager.parseDataToFilms(data, someClass: anyClass)
                                    completion(receivedData)
                                }

                            case .Failure(let error):
                                print("Alamofire error: \(error)")

                                if error.code == 1001 {
                                    self.goToNoConnectionVC()
                                }

                                print("canceled")
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                goToNoConnectionVC()
            }
        }
}
```

And I need to cancel previous downloadData request, when the new one starts, tried to cancel using currentRequest?.cancel(), but it doesn't help.

Already tried to cancelOperations using NSOperationsBlock, but it doesn't cancels current operation.

I block UI now, so that user can't send another request. But this is not correct, causes some errors later...

Pls, help

Answer (score 23):

Now on `Alamofire` 4 the `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session` is not available you should use [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1703) solution:

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default 
sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in 
dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } 
uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } 
downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() } 
}
```

and if you want to cancel (suspend, resume) a particular request you can check the request url in your `.forEach` block like this:

```
dataTasks.forEach {
                if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == url) {
                    $0.cancel()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found needed solution:

```
func stopAllSessions() {
    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.getAllTasksWithCompletionHandler { tasks in
        tasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    }
}
```

Update for Alamofire 5

```
func stopAllSessions() {
    AF.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (sessionDataTask, uploadData, downloadData) in
        sessionDataTask.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        uploadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        downloadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

To cancel all requests use

```
Alamofire.Session.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler({ dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
        dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    })
```

To cancel a request with a particular url use

```
Alamofire.Session.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler({ dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
    dataTasks.forEach {
            if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == "www.google.com") {
                $0.cancel()
            }
        
    }
    uploadTasks.forEach {
        if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == "www.google.com") {
            $0.cancel()
        }
    }
    downloadTasks.forEach {
        if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString == "www.google.com") {
            $0.cancel()
        }
        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the request, you need to trace the requests made and try to cancel it. You can store it in an array and cancel every previous request stored.
In your code you create a request:
`let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, url, headers: headers)`
but you try to cancel the `currentRequest?.cancel()` that is never valued.

Comment: I'm pretty new in swift and programming. How can I store requests in array and cancel them?

Comment: You can store it into an array, but first of all check my suggestion